# Where can i find the registry key "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop"

Tags: windows, windows-registry

Where can i find HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop?

Comment: this question sounds like a not-so-distant relative of "I can haz cheezeburger?"

Comment: You can find HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel which you can find in HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Start > Run > type " regedit" > Enter > then browse to that key.

Comment: it says Windows cannot find 'regedit'.

Comment: What about "regedt32"? It is very odd that you are missing regedit; is it possible you have a virus?  You might want to try running Malwarebytes Anti-Malware.

Comment: I found in C:\WINDOWS but what i gonna do now?

Comment: run it and find the key..

Answer (score 2):

> Start > Run > cmd.exe

then in the Command Prompt, type:

```
dir C:\WINDOWS\regedit.exe
```

and the file should be listed.

If you see instead

> Directory of C:\WINDOWS
>
> File Not Found

Then something very strange has happened.

But you can also try regedt32 in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\regedt32.exe`

If regedit.exe is where it should be, then Windows can't find it because C:\WINDOWS isn't in the path.
In a Command Prompt, enter `echo %PATH%`
Rr you can use the GUI: Start > Control Panel > System, click on the [Advanced] tab, and click the **Environment Variables** button.

In that poky little dialog, in the **System Variables** section is an entry for **Path**. Double-click on the "Path" entry, and there's an even tinier (and barely usable) dialog in which you're expected to be able to inspect and edit the semicolon-separated list of directories.

Scroll along the text field looking for entries like C:\WINDOWS and C:\WINDOWS\system32
I suspect they won't be there, in which case you'll need to add them:

Insert into the text field:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
```

ensuring that the entries are separated by a semi-colon.

Answer (score 1):

In the registry editor:

Start -> run -> regedit -> Click OK

Comment: it says Windows cannot find 'regedit'.